# How does bootstrap restrict minimum page width to 400px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've noticed that in all the examples/tutorials for twitter bootstrap that when you attempt to shrink the width of the browser it stops at 400px. e.g:

- http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html
- http://aozora.github.io/bootplus

I've examined the CSS and HTML through Chrome (Version 28.0.1500.95) and cannot figure out how it achieves this. I feel I'm missing something really obvious.

The reason I ask this is that I've followed the tutorials and I believe I've done everything required but it does not restrict the size to 400px. If I understood how the examples achieved this then perhaps I can resolve the issue within my own CSS/HTML.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? i can shrink the browser for the first link as much as I want (eventually it becomes mobile css but still shrinks).  the second link doesn't seem to work

Comment: 387px to be exact [on chrome latest on win 8].

Comment: Ok, it appears that it may be a webkit thing under Mac OSX as I have now tested under windows and only Safari enforces the min 400 px width (which I would assume is related to the 'viewport' meta tag).

Comment: None of the answers explain this effect. I'm seeing it using Bootstrap 5 on Firefox 87.0 and Chrome 90.0.  Here is a CodePen showing the effect (change view to Full Screen if needed): https://codepen.io/david263/pen/zYNaoRQ . Try narrowing your browser window. You can't get past a certain point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has nothing to do with it. Chrome appears to have OS-dependent lower limits on the size of a window — for instance, the OS X version won't allow its main window to be resized under 400 px or so, no matter what is being displayed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. I can shrink my chrome browser window so that http://placekitten.com/227/227 is visible with no white space either side.

Comment: It may be OS-dependent. I was testing on Mac OS X.

Comment: Maybe. I was testing on windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Ohk, so it's attained by specifying a `min-width` attribute to the body style.. here check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2hrm/):

css:

```
body{
   min-width:400px;
   width: auto !important;
   width:400px;
   background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
```

[result](http://jsfiddle.net/v2hrm/embedded/result/).

Comment: This does not achieve what I'm looking for as it does not appear to restrict sizing of the browser window to 400px (I tested this by adding to the default bootstrap template and loading in IE10, Firefox).